# Check null value in spfx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, reactjs

I am trying below code which will pull data using rest and bind in table but i want to display message if contact column data is blank in any items tryin below but not working

```
{this.state.items.map((post,key) =>
    { 
      if(post.Contact=null){
     <div className={ styles.bgstlVisa }><span> Message if contact field is blank.</span></div>
      }
  })}
```

this is code which bind data in table

```
{this.state.items.map((post,key) =>
          <div> 
        
        <table className={styles.tableheader} >
<thead>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Opening Hours</th>
<th>​Website​</th>
<th>Email</th>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.Title}}></td>
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.Contact}}></td>
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.Phone}}></td>
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.OpeningHours}}></td>
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.Website}}></td>
<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.Email}}></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>



          </div>     
          )}
    </div>:<div>  
    <div> 
    {this.state.items.map((post,key) =>
    { 
      if(post.Contact=null){
     <div className={ styles.bgstlVisa }><span> Message if contact field is blank</span></div>
      }
  })}

    <p></p>

        </div>
{/* </div>} */}
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to show this message in table column or below table? Also, your creating table in wrong way, It will create `table` for each list item.

Comment: i want to show message here <div className={ styles.bgstlVisa }><span> Message if contact field is blank</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript a single equals operator (`=`) is used for [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment), that is, to assign a value to a variable.

So when you do `post.Content = null`, you are *assigning* `post.Content` to *be* null.

In order to check if it *is* null, you have to use either a [double equals (`==`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) or a [triple equals (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).  The difference is that with the double equals (`==`), Javascript will try to coerce the values to be of the same type before actually comparing them, so for instance:

```
'1' == 1    // true
1 == 1      // true
'1' == '1'  // true
1 == '1'    // true
```

however the triple equals does a *strict* comparison, and does *not* convert the type when making the comparison:

```
'1' === 1    // false
1 === 1      // true
'1' === '1'  // true
1 === '1'    // false
```

It's generally considered a better practice to use the strict comparison (`===`) because then you won't run into any unexpected results  due to the type coercion.

So to check it `post.Content` is actually `null`, you want to do

```
if (post.Content === null)
```

But - that will only check if it is *exactly* `null`.  What about if it's `undefined`, or an empty string?  A better way to check if `post.Content` is just blank, because this will work whether is is `null` *or* `undefined` *or* an empty string, is to just check if it is *not* (`!`) there:

```
if (!post.Content) {
    // message if post.Content is blank for any reason
}
```